# Using System.Xml.Linq in C++/CX metro app

Tags: microsoft-metro, c++-cx

Curious to know if I can use System.Xml.Linq from a C++/CX metro app. A Metro C# app can simply reference the System.Xml.Linq.dll (which it seems to do by default), but a C++/CX app requires a WinMD file as I recall, and I cannot find such a beast for System.Xml.Linq.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you cannot use System.Xml.Linq (or anything from the System namespace) in a C++/CX metro app.  C++/CX is a wholly native projection of WinRT and so does not have access to anything in the managed world.

A group at Microsoft is working on LINQ/Reactive Extensions for native code, though: http://channel9.msdn.com/Shows/C9-GoingNative/GoingNative-9-LINQ-for-C-Native-Rx-RxC-Meet-Aaron-Lahman